# Why does chrome.storage.local.get return undefined for the value?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, undefined, google-chrome-storage

I am working on a Google Extension and using Google Storage.

Below is my code for saving and accessing the saved data. I checked the console and the data is saving correctly. However, when I access this data using chrome.storage.local.get console returns undefined for the value and not the value saved.

Code for Saving: save.js for popup.html

```
function save() {
    # the id is for a textarea in another html page
    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;

    chrome.storage.sync.set({"txt": text}, function(){
      
       # console states the correct value
       console.log('Value is set to ' + text);
     });

   # this is the page I want to retrieve the saved data in 
   window.location.replace("anotherHTMLpage.html");

}
```

Code for Accessing: retrieve.js for anotherHTMLpage.html

```
function retrieve() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["txt"], function(data) {
     
      # console says "value currently is undefined"
      console.log('Value currently is ' + data.key);

   });
  }
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome saves the data under the key you set it as. In your example, you saved it as `txt`, so it will be under `data.txt` not `data.key`.

Check out the docs for some more details https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#usage

Comment: You saved me lot of time by pointing me at the right problem! God bless you.