# How to access user data from Google Extension in another tab?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am trying to access user input data that the user inputs in the textarea of the Google Extension interface (i.e., popup.html file). I saved this data using chrome.storage.sync.set and try to access this by using chrome.storage.sync.get. (please see this for related code... [Why does chrome.storage.local.get return undefined for the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68228359/why-does-chrome-storage-local-get-return-undefined-for-the-value)).

I want to access this user input in another HTML page with a different domain (from the Google Extension id). I created this page using `chrome.tabs.create({active: false, url: "localhost.html"});`

This page contains a div that I want to display the saved text in. However, the saved data is not showing up in the div in the localhost.html page.

Comment: `localhost.html` is a file name, not a URL, so there should be a file named `localhost.html` in your extension. It's not a different domain, it's just an extension page like the popup page or the options page. You can use storage there the same way. If you have a problem then you need to show your code, see [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can I still use chrome.tabs.create for the extension? How can I open the html page extension in another tab?

Comment: I did `chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: "chrome://extensions/page.html"});` However, this isn't working.

Comment: There's no such URL either. Describe what you want to do in detail using an example.